# Authentication in Blazor and HttpContext, Razor Pages/Components

Tags: authentication, razor, blazor, httpcontext

I am awfully confused by all of the tutorials on YouTube about this topic. I want to develop an enterprise web application for practice and I am stuck at authentication. There are many videos and tutorials available but I just don't understand and/or know a few things.

Everyone I see uses ASP.NET MVC and thus .cshtml files. Do I have to do that as well or is it possible/fine if I stick with razor components as pages? I did not play around much with .cshtml and I have been told they simply are an older concept, but it seems like they are kind of a necessity. At work however only the older pages that have not been touched for ages are in that format, while our more modern uses of Blazor use razor components.

Also: About HttpContext and the IHttpContext accessor. I understand that Blazor Server applications work a little bit different and accessing the context is generally a bad idea. But watching tutorials and reading articles still confuses me about whether I should use it at all and if yes, how exactly? I have found examples where I inject the IHttpContextAccessor into a service that provides the HttpContext by passing it through from the accessor like so.

```
public class HttpContextService : IHttpContextService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public HttpContext HttpContext => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

    public HttpContextService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
}
```

But that also creates more questions: What lifetime should that service have? Scoped I assume, but there my lack of knowledge shows. Does the context change after a new HTTP request like for example when I reload the page, and wouldn't that mess with the scoped lifetime of the service?

Also I have tried the following but I am only running into an exception '*System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.*' I don't fully understand what this means, just the very surface that I could read online, but those sources generally mentioned this exception in a different context and not when executing 'HttpContext.SignInAsync()'.

```
private readonly string _scheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

private RegisterPageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new();

public async void OnRegister()
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim("LoginName", ViewModel.LoginName),
        new Claim("Password", ViewModel.Password),
    };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, _scheme);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    _authentication.Users.Add(ViewModel.LoginName, principal);

    await _httpContext.HttpContext.SignInAsync(_scheme, principal);
}
```

But maybe I am on a completely wrong track also. I have also tried to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity but I think being stuck with the IdentityUser and IdentityRole would have prevented me from implementing user accounts, roles and companies in the way I would have wanted to.

Comment: Authentication and Authorization are difficult topics.  Every time I come back to it after a month or two away, it takes a while to figure out what is going on.  However, SO is about answering specific questions.  Providing a detailed explanation of how it all works and hangs together is beyond the scope of a a SO answer.  You need to be a little more specific  [though I fully understand where you are].

Comment: Yes they are... and I see not that my question was too broad. But I suppose after bashing my head against the wall a few to many times I seem to have figured out a solid first solution. Ill share what I have learned as an answer so I might answer a few questions of people who are just as confused as I was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright after quite a while of even more research and experimentation I have figured out a decent first solution. I am not sure I would deploy that on a public website, but for a company internal webserver, it'll likely do. For starters I use cookies for authentication.

Generally the entire topic is once again easier than it looks but finding the right example for you is never easy. I hope I can give a decent starting point for the topic, but I would recommend to visit CodeWrinkles on YouTube, he makes great and explicit videos.

### Razor pages and Razor components

Razor pages can access the `HttpContext` and therefore safely sign `ClaimPrincipals` in and out. However Razor components do not have that luxury and I have not yet found a way to safely acccess the HttpContext from a Razor component. I have found solutions where the `HttpContext` was accessed in a custom service, but Microsoft recommends not only not to use the `HttpContext` directly in Razor components, but indirect implementations are also not recommended. Also I have found that solution not to work for me anyways, so why bother.

So the go to implementation for me was to create a `LoginPage.cshtml` and sign in users on this page. To logout I just navigate to my `LogoutPage.cshtml` that the user logs out immediately in `OnGetAsync()`, so this page really just displays text such as 'Logging out...', and when it's done it redirects to the login page.

For any other page I use Razor components as pages, as I find them more fun to work with and I don't really see and drawbacks that bother me.

### Configuring startup

Your applications startup will need to be configured for authentication and authorization.

First add this inbetween `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseRouting()`.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Then register authentication services with following code. That sets up your authentication to use cookies.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie();
```

### Custom authentication service: Logging in

As everyone always reminds you: Custom authentication is likely not as good as framework solutions from Microsoft, which is also why I said I likely wouldn't deploy this on a publicly accessibly website.

However I still went down this route and it is not that difficult.

1. When you start authenticating entered credentials, compare them to the database and determines whether the credentials are authentic.
2. If they are, create claims, an identity and a principal that you send back to the login page, so the `HttpContext` has someone to sign in.
3. If they are not, throw an exception to stop the process. The call of this method is wrappep in a try-catch.

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> AuthenticateUser(UserAccount user, string enteredPassword)
{
    if (!IsAuthenticated(user, enteredPassword))
        throw new InvalidCredentialException();

    var claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim("LoginName", user.LoginName),
        new Claim("Password", user.Password),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role),
    };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    
    return Task.FromResult(principal);
}
```

Note that I didn't show what `IsAuthenticated()` does, but this is the point where you check entered credentials against the database. Also note that the password is specified separately, since I use the `IPasswordHasher<TUser>` that Microsoft recommends to use. The UserAccount however. And also note again, the ClaimTypes are just makeshift in this example.

### Using the authentication service: Logging in

To get the generic stuff out of the way `ViewModel.ShowMessage` simply displays a message if something goes wrong. The `properties` determine whether your cookie persists afer the session and where to redirect after a successful login and so on and so forth.

We get the principal by using our injected authentication service with `_authentication.AuthenticateUser()`. After that was a success we simply sign in the user with out specified scheme, principal and properties. If that goes well you can look into your browser dev tools and see what cookies your browser stores. There should be some cookie authenticating you.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    try
    {
        ViewModel.ShowMessage = false;

        var principal = await _authentication.AuthenticateUser(ViewModel.Account, ViewModel.Password);
        var scheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            RedirectUri = "/",
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme, principal, properties);
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewModel.ShowMessage = true;
    }

    return Page();
}
```

### Logging out

Now, logging out is as easy as calling `HttpContext.SignOutAsync` in your `LoginPage.cshtml`. Doing that, your cookie will be destroyed and you wont be authenticated anymore. You can also delete your cookie manually, in case you need to do that during debugging.

### Registering

Registering is pretty much on you. You decide how you store your data and what data your user accounts contain. One thing however is sure: You should store sensitive information only when hashed. Using the `IPasswordHasher<TUser>` is recommended by Microsoft and implementing that is pretty easy and likely plenty safe.